# how to have a row show me 'none' instead of a 0 for a null result

Tags: sql, oracle, null

I am trying to have a result 'none' every time it gives me a null result. Right now it is giving me a 0 for a null result. How could I have a row show me 'none' instead of a 0 for a null result.

I have tried NVL(SUM(ENROLLED),'none') AS ENROLLED and it doesn't work

```
SELECT DISTINCT lt.STUDENT_ID,lt.FIRST_NAME, lt.LAST_NAME, NVL(SUM(ENROLLED),'none') AS ENROLLED
FROM STUDENT lt
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT s.STUDENT_ID, e.ENROLL_DATE,COUNT(z.COURSE_NO) AS ENROLLED
FROM   STUDENT s
LEFT   JOIN ENROLLMENT e ON s.STUDENT_ID = e.STUDENT_ID
LEFT   JOIN SECTION z ON e.SECTION_ID = z.SECTION_ID
WHERE  s.PHONE LIKE '702%'
GROUP  BY s.STUDENT_ID, e.ENROLL_DATE) rt
ON lt.STUDENT_ID = rt.STUDENT_ID
WHERE lt.PHONE LIKE '702%'
GROUP BY lt.STUDENT_ID,lt.FIRST_NAME, lt.LAST_NAME,ENROLLMENTS;
```

right now I am getting

```
STUDENT_ID FIRST_NAME                LAST_NAME                 ENROLLED
---------- ------------------------- ------------------------- -----------
       253 Walter                    Boremmann                     1 
       396 James E.                  Norman                        0 
etc
```

but I want

```
STUDENT_ID FIRST_NAME                LAST_NAME                 ENROLLED
---------- ------------------------- ------------------------- -----------
       253 Walter                    Boremmann                     1 
       396 James E.                  Norman                        none
```

Comment: This is normally something you would handle in your presentation layer, I.e. the application that shows the data. You could try `CAST`ing to a varchar type though.

Comment: try `IF(SUM(ENROLLED) = 0, 'none', SUM(ENROLLED)) as enrolled` instead

Comment: I don't see any null value in your example :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be mixing `null` values with `0`. They are not the same. `NVL` will return the first expression if it is not `null` or the second expression if the first one is `null`. As `0` is not `null` then you will always get `SUM(ENROLLED)`. You should compare using `0`.

Just change this:

```
NVL(SUM(ENROLLED),'none') AS ENROLLED
```

Into this:

```
CASE WHEN SUM(ENROLLED) = 0 THEN 'none' ELSE SUM(ENROLLED) END AS ENROLLED
```

Comment: I get an error SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER...I've tried TO_CHAR and TO_NUMBER for sum and it doesnt work...thanks for your help